# PHP - Random Ahrefs Anchor Text ? Any Advise

Tags: php, html, css

Hello I am trying to create a small php script that I have a question about all this script is suppose to do is read a local .txt file stored on my server with a list of plain urls. the script will grab 100 random urls from the .txt file and echo them into clickable anchor text anchor links based on anther text file with my keywords loaded 1 on each line. I cant figure out how to make this happen please review code below as its as far as I got. Example

list.txt

url1

url2

url3

----  need Output

keyword.txt

anchor text word 1

anchor text word 2

anchor text word 3 ect..

100 or whatever number i set.

Goal:

```
echo '<a href="url">anchor text word</a>';  <<  up to 100 or limit I set
```

```
$lines = file("list.txt");
    $keywords = file("keywords.txt");
Shuffle($lines);
Shuffle($keywords);
function url_to_clickable_link($lines) {
  return preg_replace(
  '%(https?|ftp)://([-A-Z0-9-./_*?&;=#]+)%i', 
  '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>', $lines);
}


Echo implode("<br>", array_slice(url_to_clickable_link($lines), 0, 100));
```

Got stuck did not work.

Comment: that regex is to grab links for make to clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Function names are starting lower case.
2. No regex needed.

```
$lines = file("list.txt");
$keywords = file("keywords.txt");
shuffle($lines);
shuffle($keywords);

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    echo "<a href='$lines[$i]' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>$keywords[$i]</a><br>\n";
}
```

Comment: so to be correct the final code should be >> $lines = file("list.txt");
 $keywords = file("keywords.txt");
Shuffle($lines);
Shuffle($keywords);


for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    echo "<a href='$lines[$i]'>$keywords[$i]</a><br>\n";
}

Comment: Yes :D I thought this should be clear not copy the whole code. Please write shuffle <-- lower case (!!!) https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/

Comment: Ah yes  lol this is fixed thank you please check code now.

Comment: ok I will change back.

Comment: I've updated my answer to the whole code you need.

Comment: Yes thank you for your help code is working now I forgot to setup my keywords.txt file its working now thank you so much brother!!! your the best.

Comment: You got it done. Also I wanted to ask you lets say I want to add Proper Case for Capital Letters of each word what would be the best code for this script? Thanks again buddy.

Comment: After Shuffle you could do that. `$keywords = array_map('ucwords', $keywords);`.

Comment: Ok good looking I  will try this .